# Why is タバコを買ったつもりで、お金を入れるわけだ translated to "Basically it's the money I planned on spending on cigarettes"?

Tags: meaning

> タバコをやめてからは、毎日300円ずつ貯金箱に入れている。**タバコを買ったつもりで、お金を入れるわけだ**。お金がたまったら自分へのプレゼントとして何か買うことに
> している。

1. My own understanding was:
   **{although the intention to buy cigarettes, (it was concluded that) i insert money in (the saving jar)}** .
2. Or with a rare meaning of 入れる=to pay(one's rent, etc.), i translate it as:
   **{with the intention of buying cigarettes, no wonder that one would pay/waste money}**
3. Why would 1) and 2) be wrong and {Basically it's the money I planned on spending on cigarettes.} be CORRECT??

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61298/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48067/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/78127/9831

Answer (score 2):

This requires some "feeling into the language". I will walk you through the paragraph and indicating the underlying feelings.

タバコをやめてからは、毎日300円ずつ貯金箱に入れている。（→嬉しいこと）
タバコを買ったつもりで、お金を入れるわけだ。（→タバコは好きだけれど、やめたらお金はたまる。だからその300円の貯金はタバコを吸った喜びだと思い込む）
お金がたまったら自分へのプレゼントとして何か買うことに している。（→プレゼントが買えるから、タバコが吸えなくなった慰めにはなる）

Overall, this person is really trying to stay positive about not smoking anymore. Money is the perspective he took so he feels more comfortable with his actions.

I would translate that sentence as "I am putting in the money as if I have bought cigarettes already."

In order to interpret this sentence with accuracy, I need to know the actual story. So far, this is what I understood from the paragraph.

Hope it helps!

Comment: "I am putting in the money as if I have bought cigarettes already." is exactly what i discovered to be a very probable/accurate translation of the sentence.