What is de particle marking here? 「買ったつもりで貯金する」

つもり貯金って何ですか。
…欲しいものがあっても買わないで、それを買ったつもりで貯金することです。

What is で after つもり used for?
As for me it is marking a condition, but I'm not sure.

Related, perhaps? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61298/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/78127/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/48067/9831
